# mod rewrite url for product name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Current url : http://www.domain.com/product.php?id=7&name=Shuttlecock%20SL-03
Hope to achieve : http://www.domain.com/product/Shuttlecock-SL-03

My current .htaccess look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(product)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

My product page for href look like this

```
<a href="product.php?id=7&name=Shuttlecock SL-03">Product Link </a>
```

I search everywhere and tried alot of times but failed, please help as I'm still noob in .htaccess rewrite

Comment: Try this: RewriteRule ^product/([a-z0-9_\-]+)-([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$2&name=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: thank you Ofir for your comment. However it still doesn't achieve the url I wanted.
^product/([a-z0-9_\-]+)-([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$2&name=$1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /product.php?id=7&name=$1 [L]
```

I read in your comments you did not want to include `product/`. So I've left it out.